# Filtering non-"linear", progressive values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, filter

I'm not exactly sure how to explain this, but bear with me...

I have written a program that creates random arrays of lengths that range from 0-4 like so: `[]` or `[n]` or `[n,n]` or `[n,n,n]` or `[n,n,n,n]`.

The input will be a random digit between 1-6, whereby the output, `n`, is always a multiple of the input. For example, the input might be `2` and the output might be `[2]` or `[4,8]` or `[2,4,6]`.

The output will always be sorted from lowest to highest value.

The input will always be the lowest multiple, whereas the highest multiple will always be the value of `input * 4`. For instance, if the input were `3`, the range of output would be 3-12 or 3, 6, 9, and 12.

Hypothetically, let's say the input is `4`, whereas the output, if any, is of course multiples of 4.

The only possible outputs are...

**`[]`**
**`[4]`**
`[8]`
`[12]`
`[16]`
**`[4,8]`**
`[4,12]`
`[4,16]`
`[8,12]`
`[8,16]`
`[12,16]`
**`[4,8,12]`**
`[4,8,16]`
`[4,12,16]`
`[8,12,16]`
**`[4,8,12,16]`**

What I wanted to do was filter the output so that only the bold arrays above were valid. In addition to that, I wanted to preserve any valid array elements while removing all non-"linear", progressive elements like so:

- `[4,12]` would become **`[4]`**
- `[4,8,16]` would become **`[4,8]`**
- `[8,16]` would become **`[]`**
- `[8,12,16]` would become **`[]`**
- `[12,16]` would become **`[]`**

I ended up finally figuring out how I could achieve this, but for whatever reason it took me a while to wrap my head around it; so now I'm just super curious. Is there another way to achieve this output which is definitively more efficient than the following code? Is it possible to do the same thing with some sort of loop? Are there any known algorithms out there that deal with this sort of thing?

```
    if (a[0] != 4) {
      a = [];
    } else if (a.length === 2 && a[1] != 8) {
      a.pop();
    } else if (a.length === 3 && a[1] != 8) {
      a.pop();
      a.pop();
    } else if (a.length === 3 && a[2] != 12){
      a.pop();
    }
```

Comment: Is your program generating random arrays, or are you generating arrays according to your specification? It wouldn't be hard to generate the bold arrays only, if I correctly understand your requirements.

Comment: why so complicated, if the result is only one of the numbers you give, for example 3, then you get only (without the factor) `[1]`, `[1, 2]` and `[1, 2, 3]`. then take a random array out of it.

Comment: @Justastudent The program itself is generating random arrays based on a few variables.

Comment: @NinaScholz huh?

Comment: i dont understand the concept, of generating and filtering. instead of filtering, i would go from the data and generate a result directly, i don't understand what a random element is necessary, if you still generate all possibilities and then filter the result for only the once, you could generate directly. but if you like to select from the result on by random, you could generate a number directly and buil the array upon. the factor part, could be later used, but make the probblem much more complocated than it could be. please add some more use cases and how do you get the result of it.

Comment: @NinaScholz  It's part of a backgammon game that I've begun developing. In backgammon if you rolls doubles, you not only get to move twice--once per each die--but rather twice per each die. So if you rolled double 4s, you'd be allowed to move a checker 4 times 4 spots at a time. The array above is randomly generated by calculating the potentially valid points on the board. I take the dice values and subtract them from the current point to generate the potential targets. And then I check those targets to see if an opponent has a made point or a blot on the target point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the callback in [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can handle an index argument, it can be used directly to return only the values at the 'proper' index:

```js
function filterOnFactor(arr, factor){
 return arr.filter((val,i) => ++i * factor == val);
  } 

//test
for(let arr of [[], [4], [8], [12], [16], [4, 8], [4, 12], [4, 16], [8, 12], [8, 16], [12, 16], [4, 8, 12], [4, 8, 16], [4, 12, 16], [8, 12, 16], [4, 8, 12, 16]]){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(arr), '->', JSON.stringify(filterOnFactor(arr,4)));
}
```

NB, this only works if the source is always a ascending multitude of the factor, so `[6,8,12]` would still return `[8,12]`, but according to the info, the source is always generated as an ascending multitude.

---

Just for fun, also a solution using a generator function (which is safe for all input)

```js
function* filterOnFactor(arr, factor){
    for(let i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
     if(arr[i] !== ++i * factor)break;
      yield arr[--i];
    }     
} 

//test
for(let arr of [[], [4], [8], [12], [16], [4, 8], [4, 12], [4, 16], [8, 12], [8, 16], [12, 16], [4, 8, 12], [4, 8, 16], [4, 12, 16], [8, 12, 16], [4, 8, 12, 16], [6,8,12]]){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(arr), '->', JSON.stringify([...filterOnFactor(arr,4)]));
}
```

Comment: this'll get marked as the solution for its eloquence. is that syntax ES6? so much more concise o:

Comment: also, is there any way to break out of the filter function?? for instance, i know that the 4th value of any array will be valid whereby the first 3 values are valid

Comment: The arrow (`=>`) function is indeed ES6. Great isn't it :) So is the `... of ...` in the test functions. The ES5 equivalent for the function would be `return arr.filter(function(val,i) {return ++i * factor == val;});`

Comment: The break out isn't possible inside the filter directly (could be emulated by returning true if a flag is set), but it could be checked beforehand: `return arr.length > 3 && arr[3] == 16 ? arr : arr.filter((val,i) => ++i * factor == val);`

Comment: yeah, it really is `() => 'AMAZING'`

Answer (score 2):

Because your arrays have fixed length, being efficient or not is not really a concern.

That said, it is possible to write your manual case distinction in a more generic way. This might save a couple of comparisons with the array length, but the greatest advantage is that it does not hardcode values or assumes a maximum array length.

**Idea.** Start at the beginning of the array and then, for every element, check if it is the expected multiple. If not, cut off the rest of the array from that point onwards.

```js
function filterMultiples(arr, firstMultiple) {
  let badIndex = arr.findIndex((value, index) =>
    (value !== (index + 1) * firstMultiple)
  );
  if (badIndex < 0) {
    return arr;
  }
  return arr.slice(0, badIndex);
}

function test(arr, firstMultiple = 4) {
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(arr) + ' is filtered to ' +
    JSON.stringify(filterMultiples(arr, firstMultiple)) +
    ` (multiples of ${firstMultiple})`
  );
}

test([4, 8, 16]); // [4, 8]
test([2]); // []
test([4, 6, 12]); // [4]
test([2, 4, 6, 8, 9], 2); // [2, 4, 6, 8]

// tests from question
test([4,12]); // [4]
test([4,8,16]); // [4,8]
test([8,16]); // []
test([8,12,16]); // []
test([12,16]); // []
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The CSS in the above snippet is only for display purposes, the import part is `filterMultiples`.

**Explanation.** We [find the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the first element that is not the expected value. If no such element is found, all values are as expected and we return the original array. Otherwise, we return only the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) of the array up to but not including the first unexpected value.

**Alternative.** If you want to modify the original array, you can write the function as follows.

```
function filterMultiples(arr, firstMultiple) {
  let badIndex = arr.findIndex((value, index) =>
    (value !== (index + 1) * firstMultiple)
  );
  if (badIndex >= 0) {
    arr.splice(badIndex);
  }
}
```

This approach uses [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: it's getting late here. i'll have to come back tomo so i have time to process your answer. it's funny i started reading the beginning of it and it was incredibly similar to an idea i just had. initially i tried using the `filter()` method and wasn't able to think of a way to make it work. but i just realized that if i track the `index` of each element and compare it to the prior `element` to see if it is a multiple, i can eliminate them like that; this is almost identical to how i've interpreted your suggestion in the **Idea.** paragraph. i'll get back to you tomo!!

Comment: @Anthony Sure! Take your time and then please let me know if my answer helped by either [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) my answer or leaving another comment :-)

Comment: This (`value !== (index + 1) * firstMultiple`) is brilliant. Last night after logging off I realize the "similar" idea I thought wouldn't work. Also, you were correct when responding to Nina. I should of also noted in my question that valid sequences must start with either `[]` or `input` followed by linear multiples of that input, whereby invalid sequences can also have valid subsequences. i'm going to read the other answers before i select yours as the answer, but you def get a vote up

Comment: i'm going to mark other buddy's answer as the solution since it's a lot more concise, but your answer/info def helped big time

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the values and then filter the arrays.

```js
function sequence() {
    var i = 1;
    return function (b) {
        return b === factor * i++;
    };
}

function validate(a) {
    return a.filter(sequence());
}

function notEmpty(a) {
    return a.length;
}

var data = [[], [4], [8], [12], [16], [4, 8], [4, 12], [4, 16], [8, 12], [8, 16], [12, 16], [4, 8, 12], [4, 8, 16], [4, 12, 16], [8, 12, 16], [4, 8, 12, 16]],
    factor = 4,
    result = data
        .map(validate)
        .filter(notEmpty);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is good, but I believe OP wants to do partial filtering as well. For example, `[4, 12]` would be mapped to `[4]` and then accepted. They also seem to not want to filter out arrays like `[8]` or `[8, 12]`, but map them to `[]` instead.

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah, i should've been more clear in my question about that.